# How can I fix CSS transitions on react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a simple login/signup screen. I'm toggling the login/signup forms through a state variable. The toggle works fine, but everything happens in just one frame and I want to animate the height transition of the form container, as well as fade the forms in or out as they switch. I am struggling to understand/tame the transition property and so far I managed to transition the height, but it only works once, and of course, I haven't been able to animate the forms opacity. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing? code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-flower-e42dj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you paste your code here, but anyways
you can use CSS keyframes for fade-in effect.

```
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 1s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 1s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

When you are adding class to show login form and signup form, add this "fade-in" class too. Similarly, you can write the same for fading out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-wildflower-dwn0q?file=/src/App.js

Updated your code for your reference.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will the same work with the form container height?

Comment: You can do the same for whichever component you want to fade in, or group them in one and apply on that group. For height, if you want to give the stretch effect then you can use width CSS transition.